# MS store app on pendrive run fine one PC, TOTAL erase on other PC

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, microsoft-store

I installed 3 Microsoft store apps on my NTFS pen-drive.
I inserted the pendrive into another windows 10 PC.
Now, not only the apps didn't show in the list, but when I inserted it on the original one, the app was

> 0 bytes

Now, installing again and again seems not to be a good option. So what should I do to ensure that the app does not get damaged? (I HAVE to plug the drive into other PC.)

Edit 0: Sorry, I forgot the  point that due to low disk space, I have been installing apps on pen drive.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/285410/how-to-install-.appx-or-.appxbundle-software-on-windows-10/

Comment: The only way to download it on one machine and use it on another is to find or get the appx and sideload it. Just installing it on a USB stick and hoping it magically registers itself on another machine is not how it works.

Comment: No, that's not the problem, you misunderstood it. I use pen drive to transfer data, and the apps vanish. I am looking for a way to protect my apps.

Comment: Downoading the apps use GBs of my conection. They cost me time and money.

Comment: So download it *once* as an `appx` and install it once *normally*. You are not installing it properly on the second machine, hence it has no idea that you want it. You remove the drive from the first machine and so Windows can't find it and marks it as such. You think I'm not understanding you but I am, you are just making a wrong assumption about how things work. You will have to download an `appx` file (https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/download-an-appx-file-from-the-microsoft-store-on-windows-10/) and sideload it on both machines to install it. Don't install to removable drives.

Comment: If you want to clarify your question then you can [edit] it to provide details on what your problem is, why you have to do it this way and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Pl. see the edit