# Run MS Store Apps saved on external drive on a new PC

Tags: external-hard-drive, windows-11, windows-store-app

I have a few MS Store app/games that are stored on an external drive. I have recently moved to a new PC, and do not see a way to get them running. I saved them to the drive by opening the storage menu on my old PC (Windows 10 Pro) and selecting the "move" button. Afterwards, they just appeared in the start menu on the old PC.

On new new PC (Windows 11 Pro) the apps do not appear in start (I did not think they would), but do not see a way to even run them. The folder is called `WindowsApps` on the drive, and I keep getting permission errors when trying to open it. My thought was to just install the app again, move it, the have Windows recognize that is is already there and not move it, but show it in start.

However, Windows will not let me make a copy of the folder, giving me a "Your organization does not let you save files here" message (The PC is also not enrolled in an organization), and I don't want to risk having the files deleted or overwritten.

**So how can I run the apps stored externally on my new PC?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Make use of the game (AirPort City) cross-platform support to play on your new PC without losing your progress.

---

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/airport-city/9wzdncrfjchj (emphasis mine)

> **What's new in this version**
> Winter has come to Airport City! The Christmas Journey offers amazing daily surprizes, and the citizens are ready to take on the Holiday Rush. Join them — it’s gonna be fun!
>
> **FIXES & IMPROVEMENTS**
>
> - Cross-platform support! **Play on different devices without losing any progress.**
> - Bug fixes.

---

Making a regular "app" work on an external drive on different devices is not something simple and making a MS Store app moved to an external drive work on a computer having a different Windows version certainly will not be easier. To learn about this topic, I suggest you to learn about portable applications.

Resources

- [Portable application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application)
- [Why aren't all applications 'portable'?](https://superuser.com/q/1137/152004)

Related

- [MS store app on pendrive run fine one PC, TOTAL erase on other PC](https://superuser.com/q/1618315/152004)